# Load ssl via relative `src`

Tags: html, ssl

Haven't been able to find anything posted about this, but is it possible to load `https://` Via a relative URL?

On my testing server that is located at `example.com:3000` I reference my scripts explicitly like so :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com:3000/js/dist.js"></script>
```

This is fine but anytime I switch over to production I need to change this to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/js/dist.js"></script>
```

What I am wondering is if it is possible to load it like below but ensure that it will be loaded over ssl:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dist.js"></script>
```